# Animating background position on hover

Tags: javascript, button, hover

Can anyone give me some advises;
on the best way to create buttons with animated background position on hover.

Like the buttons on this page, about us, make a donation etc

http://nationallgbtmuseum.org/#/home/

many thanks for your input.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? The idea is we help you with what you have, not do it for you.

Comment: I'm not asking you to do it. I'm asking the best way to do it?

Comment: I would like to do it with javascript but I have no idea how. I can do it easy with CSS animations @keyframes animatedBackground {
 from { background-position: 0 0; }
 to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of some CSS3 animation to achieve this.

One way of doing this is below. View this snippet in a webkit based browser like Chrome. You can adapt this for cross-browser by adding vendor-prefixes and the standard one.

***Snippet:***

```css
div {
    width: 240px; height: 240px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/32/32);
    background-position: -640px 640px;
}
div:hover {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
    -webkit-animation-name: anim;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear ;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim { 
    0% { background-position: -640px 640px; }
    100% { background-position: 640px -640px; }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```